# BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer or hex string

Tags: node.js, express, routes

```
app.get('/inventory/my-items', async (req, res) => {
       const cursor = inventoryCollection.find({});
       const result = cursor.toArray();
       res.send(result);
     });
```

"BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer" I have found this error in the server-side terminal when creating the following route (/inventory/my-items) but when changing the route like (/my-items/get-items) it works perfectly

Comment: whats the error? what do you change that makes it work? Please read SO [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question

Comment: "BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer"
I have found this error in the server-side terminal when creating the following route (`/inventory/my-items`) but when changing the route like (`/my-items/get-items`) it works perfectly